# please help debug iOS crash in [GCKDeviceManager appDidEnterBackground]

Tags: ios, chromecast

We use crashlytics for crash reporting and just saw the following EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3ad10b26 objc_msgSend + 5
1  Fandor                         0x000e6463 -[GCKDeviceManager appDidEnterBackground] (GCKDeviceManager.m:238)
2  CoreFoundation                 0x30606119 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
3  CoreFoundation                 0x3057a257 _CFXNotificationPost + 1718
4  Foundation                     0x30f5fc2d -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 76
5  UIKit                          0x32e3a681 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 908
6  UIKit                          0x32dbbae1 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 764
7  UIKit                          0x32dbb721 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
8  UIKit                          0x32e20b3d _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 664
9  GraphicsServices               0x3524c70d _PurpleEventCallback + 608
10 GraphicsServices               0x3524c2f7 PurpleEventCallback + 34
11 CoreFoundation                 0x3060e9df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
12 CoreFoundation                 0x3060e97b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
13 CoreFoundation                 0x3060d14f __CFRunLoopRun + 1398
14 CoreFoundation                 0x30577c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
15 CoreFoundation                 0x30577a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices               0x3524b283 GSEventRunModal + 138
17 UIKit                          0x32e1b049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
18 Fandor                         0x00064387 main (main.m:16)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS generally means that you are sending a obj c message to an invalid memory address. Usually this happens because an object that you are using has been deallocated. Check out that.

Comment: have you checked this line: GCKDeviceManager.m:238? Like @VelmuruganS says, it usually means some object is over-released.

Comment: That code is in the google library.  We don't have access to it.

Comment: @DanAronson Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Are you perchance using CastVideos-ios as a base?

I can trigger this if I open my Chromecast sender app and then quickly enter background. I think GCKDeviceManager has some race condition.

Comment: Just to check, which version of the iOS SDK is this using - 2.3.0?

Comment: Does anyone know if this issue was ever fixed in a later release of the Google Chromecast iOS Sender library?